# where to use update panel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a custom treeview which i create programmatically as there is a need of specific layout which is not achievable using asp.net treeview.It is on a master page.When i click on treenodes the content area refreshes after a postback.There is a page category.aspx which is a content page of this master page.I have a  user control in that content area named products.aspx.Now i want to use ajax to prevent the postback which happens when i click on treenode.I tried putting user control in updatepanel and treeview as well in updatepanel but to no awail.

How to use updatepanel in this scenerio.

Comment: How are you creating your custom treeview?  Are you using LinkButtons?  Are you deriving from the ASP.Net Treeview?

Answer (score 0):

UpdatePanel must be used with the development of User control or Custom Control. [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check [How Ajax for ASP.NET updatepanels work](http://www.aspcode.net/How-Ajax-for-ASPNET-updatepanels-work.aspx)